# How do I get my program to call a function and write to 'Output" window?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I’m trying to get this program to write to the ‘Output’ or Immediate window.  The program runs ok but how do I call the piece of code that I need to be executed in the output window?  I gues what I’m asking is how do I get my program to call this function?

```
  public class UtilityTest
{
    [Test]
    public void FindConflictingReferences()
    {
        var assemblies = GetAllAssemblies(@"C:\MyProject\bin\debug");

        var references = GetReferencesFromAllAssemblies(assemblies);

        var groupsOfConflicts = FindReferencesWithTheSameShortNameButDiffererntFullNames(references);

        foreach (var group in groupsOfConflicts)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Possible conflicts for {0}:", group.Key);
            foreach (var reference in group)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("{0} references {1}",
                                      reference.Assembly.Name.PadRight(25),
                                      reference.ReferencedAssembly.FullName);
            }
        }
    }
```

UPDATE:

I've ran it with debug window using F5.  Also put break point in the code but that code does not seem to run.  Is there something I'm missing from the default page that can call the method?

Comment: You can create a new console application project and reference the unit test project(I assume the test code is there) and create a new instance of Utility test and call the FindConflictingReferences method and it should work.

Comment: This is a unit test right? If so, in VS2012, right-click on the method signature (or somewhere inside the method), and there should be a context option to run the test. If you are using the NUnit framework, you should also be able to run the test from the NUnit test runner, by loading in the test assembly first.

Answer (score 0):

It should work the way you wrote it. You just need to make sure you debug the program to see the output in Visual Studio. By default, the key to do that is F5.

Also, in the output window, you need to make sure the drop down is set to "Debug", not something else like "Build".